# Colored Man Page and source Issues

Tags: terminal, man

i'm using alacritty as my terminal on Fedora 38 Workstation.

I have tried few different ways of getting colored man pages working but none are panning out, even if i go into the GNOME terminal (to rule out something particular with Alacritty). Funnily enough, the alternate TTYs seem to have it by default even though my config wasn't working, it's just some cyan/gray/white colorscheme.

**what i've tried so far for colored man pages:**

I tried the methods here, using `most` and `less`: https://www.2daygeek.com/get-display-view-colored-colorized-man-pages-linux/

and here, an alternate way of doing it with `less`, plus a way of using `bat` instead: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Man_page#Color_for_man_pages

- **bat kind of worked**, i got colors, but the man pages were messed up--they had extra numbers and symbols that i suppose are formatting that is usually stripped away

---

As a side note, `source ~/.bashrc` doesn't really work (consistently?) for me, either. that's an issue but not the main one re: colored man pages since it doesn't work in new terminal windows either...but: I kept testing it against making a new terminal and it just wasn't taking changes. I haven't done much customization before so I am not sure if this is new or not, but it definitely isn't working 100%.

as an example, from my history:

```
 956  sudo dnf remove most #uninstalled most since it wasn't working for colorizing.
 957  nvim ~/.bashrc #removed export PAGER="most"
 958  source ~/.bashrc
 959  nvim .bashrc #checked that i actually saved the change. i had.
 960  source ~/.bashrc #tried source again
 961  man ls #getting an error that most is not installed, because it's still the pager despite sourcing 2x so far.
 962  ... #a few more source + man test attempts, none successful. only seemed to resource when i opened a new terminal
```

anyone have input? i am not sure what i'm doing wrong. thanks in advance.

something i looked into is whether my .bash_profile could be mucking things up but as i understand it, it should be pulling in the .bashrc file too so that shouldn't be an issue even if it were being loaded instead

Comment: " #removed export PAGER="most"" if you remove that line from your bashrc and source it again, that does not mean that an already exported `PAGER` variable is going to vanish.

Comment: `export GROFF_NO_SGR=1`

Comment: @muru ok, i guess that makes sense. i thought re-sourcing would have 'erased' it. thanks

Comment: also wanted to mention that `batman` works for me.